# POI data provider installation SSH

Tags: fiware, fiware-poi, fiware-sagitta, fiware-pegasus

I am trying to set up a blueprint instance in Fiware lab of the POI data provider and I get an Error

```
Status: ERROR
Error: Error installing a product.Description:com.telefonica.euro_iaas.paasmanager.exception.ProductInstallatorException:
```

Error installing product poi_dp-3.3.3 Error invokg SDC to Install Productpoi_dp-3.3.3 3.3.3 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

Answer (score 1):

Correction in https://github.com/Chiru/FIWARE-POIDataProvider/ .

Old blueprint did not seem to work.
Anyway, you can install the POI GE from GitHub on the Ubuntu 14.04 image https://github.com/Chiru/FIWARE-POIDataProvider/blob/master/docs/POI_Data_Provider__Installation_and_Administration_Guide.md .

Comment: Release 4.4 is published.